# SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths failed

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, pdo

I setup SSL from: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/creating-ssl-files-using-openssl.html

The database server shows SSL is enabled. On the web server, I can do:

```
mysql -h xx.xx.xxx.xxx --ssl-ca=ca.pem --ssl-cert=client-cert.pem --ssl-key=client-key.pem -uMyUser -p
```

Assuming I'm in the directory with the SSL certs, it works fine. If I move out of the directory I get:

> ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error:
>   SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths failed

Now in PHP, I have:

```
<?php
if(file_exists('/ssl/client-key.pem')) echo 'wtf';
if(file_exists('/ssl/client-cert.pem')) echo 'wtf';
if(file_exists('/ssl/ca.pem')) echo 'wtf';
function newPDO($host, $user, $password, $database) {
        $ssl = array(
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY    =>'/ssl/client-key.pem',
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT=>'/ssl/client-cert.pem',
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA    =>'/ssl/ca.pem'
        );
        try {
                $dbl = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $user, $password, $ssl);
                $dbl->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();

        }
        return $dbl;
}

$dbl = newPDO('xx.xx.xxx.xxx', 'user', 'pass' ,'database');

?>
```

> OUTPUT: wtfwtfwtfSQLSTATE[HY000] [2026] SSL connection error:
>   SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths failed

This is the same error I get when the path is wrong in SSH. I verified the path in PHP, and the output shows those files exist. I am using PHP 5.4.16.

Ideas?

Comment: Do not include tags in question title, thank you.

Comment: I'm getting this same error on a Rails app using Amazon RDS

Comment: I also used RDS. Did you verify that the path to those certificates actually exist? In PHP would be something like if(file_exists('/ssl/client-key.pem')) echo 'exists';

Answer (score -2):

```
sudo yum remove php-mysql
sudo yum install php-mysqlnd
sudo reboot
```